# how to convert date format in php from an existing format

Tags: php, date, converters

In a database, the date is stored like this: `14 May 2020 22:25`

I was wondering, when reading this line from database, and change the output to this: `14-5-2020`, is it possible to convert this easily? because sometimes i want to output `14 May 2020 22:25` and sometimes i want to output `14-5-2020`. And if is possible, i only want to store 1 format in the database

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i', '14 May 2020 22:25');
echo $date->format('d-n-Y'); //14-5-2020
```

As mentioned in the comment by @Sammitch, you can use PHP DateTime Class to achieve this. 
You can format the Date and Time, once you create it. Be sure to check the format guide. Given below as link.

Useful Links:

[Formatting DateTime in PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

[PHP DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)